# Sympy/Numpy returning syntax error

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm trying to run this simple code block and it keeps throwing a syntax error and it's not pointing out where it's occuring.

I'm running python in a console so it won't let me type past the if statement:

```
for p in arange(2,3,0.01):
    l1 = Line(f(x,p))
    l2 = Line(g(x))
    if len(intersection(l1,l2) == 1:
```

Comment: len(intersection(l1,l2) == 1, add a ')' at before the ' ==', basically you want to finish the length function and then compare to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a ")" missing here.

Change line 4 as following:

```
if len(intersection(l1,l2)) == 1:
```

It should fix your problem.